# How to calculate the orthogonality error between sine and cosine wave?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

As the picture below(assume the magnitude is the same),the zero-crossing points of the SIN and COS signals do not occur at the precise distance of 90°.So I want to figure out the φ which is φx-φy.
[PICTURE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVv9W.png)
Through information research,I found that the orthogonality can be calculated out of the magnitude of two 90° angle shifted components.Possible angle combinations are 45° and 135°, 135° and 225°, 225° and 315° or 315° and 45°. And the orthogonality error can be calculated by the equations below:
$$
M_{45}=\sqrt{X_{45}^{2}+Y_{45}^{2}} \\
M_{135}=\sqrt{X_{135}{ }^{2}+Y_{135}{ }^{2}} \\
\varphi=2^{*} \arctan \left(\frac{M_{135}-M_{45}}{M_{135}+M_{45}}\right)
$$
$$
 X_{45}, X_{135}: \quad  Cosine~values~at~45^{\circ}  ~and ~ 135^{\circ} 
$$
$$
{Y}_{45},{Y}_{135}: \quad  Sine~values~at~45^{\circ} ~ and~  135^{\circ} 
$$
I wonder how these equations are derived?

Comment: You have two *sinusoidal* signals $X$ and $Y$. **Not** $\cos(X)$ and $\sin(Y)$. I suppose you could view $X$ as the amplified, slightly-phase-shifted, vertically-offset transformation of the cosine of the horizontal coordinate of your graph, but simply calling it a cosine is misleading.

Comment: It might help if the question text included the information about where you found your formulas.